# How To Run Multiple "awk" commands:

Tags: unix, awk

Would like to run multiple "awk" commands in single script ..
For example Master.csv.gz located at /cygdrive/e/Test/Master.csv.gz and 
Input files are located in different sub directories like /cygdrive/f/Jan/Input_Jan.csv.gz & /cygdrive/f/Feb/Input_Feb.csv.gz  and so on ..
All input files are *.gz extension files.

Below commands are working fine while executing command one by one:

Command#1

```
awk ' BEGIN {FS = OFS = ","} FNR==NR {a[$2] = $0; next} ($2 in a) {print $0}'  <(gzip -dc /cygdrive/e/Test/Master.csv.gz) <(gzip -dc /cygdrive/f/Jan/Input_Jan.csv.gz) >>Output.txt
```

Output#1:

```
Name,Age,Location
abc,20,xxx
```

Command#2

```
awk ' BEGIN {FS = OFS = ","} FNR==NR {a[$2] = $0; next} ($2 in a) {print $0}'  <(gzip -dc /cygdrive/e/Test/Master.csv.gz) <(gzip -dc /cygdrive/f/Feb/Input_Feb.csv.gz) >>Output.txt
```

Output#2:

```
Name,Age,Location
def,40,yyy
```

cat Output.txt

```
Name,Age,Location
abc,20,xxx
def,40,yyy
```

Have tried below commands to run in via single script , got error:

Attempt#1:  awk -f Test.awk

cat Test.awk

```
awk ' BEGIN {FS = OFS = ","} FNR==NR {a[$2] = $0; next} ($2 in a) {print $0}'  <(gzip -dc /cygdrive/e/Test/Master.csv.gz) <(gzip -dc /cygdrive/f/Jan/Input_Jan.csv.gz) >>Output.txt
awk ' BEGIN {FS = OFS = ","} FNR==NR {a[$2] = $0; next} ($2 in a) {print $0}'  <(gzip -dc /cygdrive/e/Test/Master.csv.gz) <(gzip -dc /cygdrive/f/Feb/Input_Feb.csv.gz) >>Output.txt
```

Error : Attempt#1:  awk -f Test.awk

```
awk: Test.awk:1:          ^ invalid char ''' in expression
awk: Test.awk:1:          ^ syntax error
```

Attempt#2:  sh Test.sh

cat Test.sh

```
#!/bin/sh
awk ' BEGIN {FS = OFS = ","} FNR==NR {a[$2] = $0; next} ($2 in a) {print $0}'  <(gzip -dc /cygdrive/e/Test/Master.csv.gz) <(gzip -dc /cygdrive/f/Jan/Input_Jan.csv.gz) >>Output.txt
awk ' BEGIN {FS = OFS = ","} FNR==NR {a[$2] = $0; next} ($2 in a) {print $0}'  <(gzip -dc /cygdrive/e/Test/Master.csv.gz) <(gzip -dc /cygdrive/f/Feb/Input_Feb.csv.gz) >>Output.txt
```

Error : Attempt#2:  sh Test.sh

```
Test.sh: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `('
```

Desired Output:

```
Name,Age,Location
abc,20,xxx
def,40,yyy
```

Looking for your suggestions ..

**Update#2-Month Name**
Ed Morton, Thanks for the inputs, however the output order are not proper , "Jan2014" is print on next line , please suggest

cat Output.txt:

```
Name,Age,Location
abc,20,xxx
Jan2014
def,40,yyy
Feb2014
```

Expected Output

```
Name,Age,Location
abc,20,xxx,Jan2014
def,40,yyy,Feb2014
```

Comment: Put them both in a bash script ?

Comment: You may want to use what is described in http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1466678 : `FILENAME==ARGV[1]`, `FILENAME==ARGV[2]`... Is this what you mean?

Comment: Jidder , am getting error in bash script as well, error message : Test.sh: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `('

Comment: @fedorqui An easier way is `ARGIND==1` `ARGIND==2`

Comment: @Jidder interesting, thanks! I didn't know it.

Comment: @AVN you probably have some problems with your file. Can you do `cat -vEt file` and see if it has some weird characters?

Comment: Fedorqui, Please find outcome of cat -VEt under "Update Comments" area

Comment: @AVN `sh` is not necessarily `bash`. If you want to use bash-specific constructs than call `bash`, don't call `sh`.

Comment: Ed Morton, Thanks, should I call like  bash Test.txt instead of sh Test.sh ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need is:

```
#!/bin/bash
awk -F, 'FNR==NR{a[$2]; next} $2 in a'            \
     <(gzip -dc /cygdrive/e/Test/Master.csv.gz)   \
     <(gzip -dc /cygdrive/f/Jan/Input_Jan.csv.gz) \
     <(gzip -dc /cygdrive/f/Feb/Input_Feb.csv.gz) \
         >> Output.txt
```

If you want to print the month name too then the simplest thing would be:

```
#!/bin/bash
awk -F, 'FNR==NR{a[$2]; next} $2 in a{print $0, mth}' \
     <(gzip -dc /cygdrive/e/Test/Master.csv.gz)             \
     mth="Jan" <(gzip -dc /cygdrive/f/Jan/Input_Jan.csv.gz) \
     mth="Feb" <(gzip -dc /cygdrive/f/Feb/Input_Feb.csv.gz) \
         >> Output.txt
```

but you could remove the redundant specifying of the month name 3 times on each line with:

```
#!/bin/bash
mths=(Jan Feb)
awk -F, 'FNR==NR{a[$2]; next} $2 in a{print $0, mth}' \
     <(gzip -dc /cygdrive/e/Test/Master.csv.gz)             \
     mth="${mths[$((i++))]}" <(gzip -dc "/cygdrive/f/${mths[$i]}/Input_${mths[$i]}.csv.gz") \
     mth="${mths[$((i++))]}" <(gzip -dc "/cygdrive/f/${mths[$i]}/Input_${mths[$i]}.csv.gz") \
         >> Output.txt
```

Comment: Ed Morton , would like to know where to use {print $0,"Jan2014"} while executing the Input_Jan.csv.gz into the Output.txt and {print $0,"Feb2014"} while executing Input_Feb.csv.gz into the Output.txt , so that i can track the Output lines from which source files !!!

Comment: Ed Morton, wow excellent input, Thanks for the inputs, however the output order are not proper , "Jan2014" is print on next line , please suggest , have edited question and posted the output under "Update#2-MonthName"

Comment: I can't imagine what would cause that unless you have OFS defined to be a newline or your files were generated on Windows and so contain spurious control-M characters in which case set `RS='\n\r'` or remove them using `gsub(/\r/,"")` or similar.

Answer (score 0):

Your first attempt failed because you were trying to call [`awk`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html) in an [`awk`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html) script, and your second attempt failed because the `bash` process substitution, `<(...)`, is not [defined by POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html), and is not guaranteed to work with [`/bin/sh`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sh.html). Here is an [`awk`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/awk.html) script that should work.

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
BEGIN {
    if (ARGC < 3) exit 1;
    ct = "cat ";
    gz = "gzip -dc "
    f = "\"" ARGV[1] "\"";
    c = (f~/\.gz$/)?gz:ct;
    while ((c f | getline t) > 0) {
        split(t, a, ",");
        A[a[2]] = t;
    }
    close(c f);
    for (n = 2; n < ARGC; n++) {
        f = "\"" ARGV[n] "\"";
        c = (f~/\.gz$/)?gz:ct;
        while ((c f | getline t) > 0) {
            split(t, a, ",");
            if (a[2] in A) print t;
        }
        close(c f);
    }
    exit;
}
```

usage

```
script.awk /cygdrive/e/Test/Master.csv.gz /cygdrive/f/Jan/Input_Jan.csv.gz
script.awk /cygdrive/e/Test/Master.csv.gz /cygdrive/f/Feb/Input_Feb.csv.gz
```

or

```
script.awk /cygdrive/e/Test/Master.csv.gz /cygdrive/f/Jan/Input_Jan.csv.gz\
           /cygdrive/f/Feb/Input_Feb.csv.gz
```

Comment: Thanks kdhp for your inputs, have modified the script and checked but "Output.txt" file is empty ...

Comment: or maybe O.P. can use `#!/bin/bash`? Also likely that windows data will have `\r\n` line-endings. Do we need `gzip ... | tr -d '\015' | awk ...` ? Good luck to all.

Comment: Shetter ,Thanks for the inputs,  Tried #!/bin/bash  as well , "Output.txt" is empty ..

Comment: @AVN you are running a script that requires 2 input streams and calling it with 1 input stream. Why would you expect to get any output? Come on, THINK a little about what you're doing.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I changed the `sh` script to an `awk` script, it should work now.

Comment: You're making this far more complicated than it has to be and trying to use awk as a shell.

Comment: @EdMorton The only other POSIX compatible options that I can think of are to create temporary files, or to print a file separator between the files. The `awk` example seems simpler to me than either of those.

Comment: The OP isn't asking specifically for a POSIX solution and your awk script is not POSIX awk anyway.

Comment: @EdMorton The original question did not specify any utilities other than `sh`, `awk`, `cat`, and `gzip`, so I did not make the assumption that non-standard utilities were available. Which part of the script are you referring to? The only non-POSIX part that I can see is `gzip`.

Comment: The OP uses bash-specific constructs in his posted **working** scripts and said in his comments that he tried using bash to fix the problem he had running yours. `delete array` is non-POSIX, and whether POSIX or not (I really don't know, nor care) use of non-parenthesized ternary expressions will produce syntax errors in some awks in some situations (e.g. BSD awk with print) and YMMV with testing for getline success return being specifically 1 when testing for > 0 will work on all awks. There are other issues too like `c f` should be `c "\"" f "\""`.